# can I put a customized windows server core in azure instance?

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, windows-server-2016

I am a dot net developer.I am using azure students subscription. I am running a windows service app which compile cpp file, run and collect output and store in database. It uses mingw for compiling. the software hosted in a windows vm. But windows vm cost for student but container instance does'nt.Now I want to run windows server core on azure container and host the service app with remote desktop in windows server core . Is it possible? if possible what is the procedure?

Comment: As I known, it's not possible currently.:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, now you can install Windows Server 2016 Datacenter - Server Core:

https://portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.WindowsServer2016DatacenterServerCore-ARM